# Proving theorems about ZFC by proving them for an arbitrary model.

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, model-theory

To prove that a statement follows from the group axioms, we typically write:

> Let $G$ denote an arbitrary group... Then... Thus, it s a theorem of the group axioms that...

Presumably, this form of argument should be equally useful in set theory. So to prove that a statement follows from ZFC, it would be useful to be able to write:

> Let $Z$ denote an arbitrary model of ZFC. Then... Thus, it s a theorem of ZFC that...

What is the appropriate definition of "model of ZFC" such that this kind of reasoning works?

Comment: "Model of ZFC" is just a special case of "model of T" where T is a first-order theory (another example being the group axioms.)

Comment: "Presumably, this form of argument should be equally useful in set theory." Indeed. This works because of the completeness theorem: if all models of a theory satisfy a given sentence then there exists a proof of that sentence from the theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same definition of a model in any other theory.

This is a set which encodes a structure which interprets the language of set theory, in which the axioms of ZFC are true. In this case this means a pair $\langle M,E\rangle$ such that $E$ is a binary relation and $M$ is non-empty, and the axioms of ZFC are true in this structure.

Comment: So just to clarify: we can prove theorems about ZFC by proving them for an arbitrary model, and this works even though we have no guarantee that ZFC has actually got a model (because it cannot be proved consistent)?

Comment: Yes. When we prove something from the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ it will be true in every universe of $\sf ZFC$, and in every model of $\sf ZFC$ if such exists.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the result holds as you stated, by the completeness theorem (taking as model any structure $(M,E)$ that satisfies the ZFC axioms).

That being said, I am not sure that we actually use this result in full generality in practice. However, what is common is to argue about *transitive* set models (of enough set theory), and then conclude that the result indeed holds, due to the reflection principle. This approach admits quite a few wrinkles, and it is a powerful technique in infinitary combinatorics and set theoretic topology.